# Installation of bioperl in Ubuntu 12.04LS

Tags: perl, ubuntu, installation, cpan, bioperl

I am trying to install Bioperl package in Perl environment of version 5.20.0,
But I am unable to get in to the stuffs.
Idea and suggestion of websites varies and its going to be uneasy for me.
Please suggest me the protocols for installing Bioperl in Ubuntu 12.04LS.

Comment: askubuntu.com or http://bit.ly/U6xsGL perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Installing_BioPerl_on_Ubuntu_Server

Install and Configure a Basic Ubuntu Server

Do install then configure.

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install ssh screen
apt-get clean
```

Install as much as possible with apt-get

Enable Universe and Multiverse in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
apt-get update
apt-get install \
 lynx unzip zip ncftp gcc libc6-dev make mysql-server apache2 \
 perl libgd-gd2-perl libcgi-session-perl libclass-base-perl libexpat1-dev
apt-get clean
```

Install CPAN and perl modules not available via apt-get

```
cpan -i 'Text::Shellwords'  # choose defaults if first time
```

Install BioPerl

```
cd /tmp
wget -N http://bioperl.org/DIST/current_core_unstable.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf current_core_unstable.tar.bz2
cd bioperl-*
perl Build.PL   # choose the defaults
./Build test
./Build install
```

Comment: Yes .. I have followed this procedure earlier .. but bioperl in not installed neither its package were enabled.

Comment: Did you get any error while following above or all went fine?

Comment: This is not recommended because the bioperl version you are installing above is more than 7 years old. This will lead to a lot of issues that have been fixed. It is recommended to install the latest stable release from CPAN, or the latest development version from Github.

Comment: Thanks All .. !! If hav got the fault ... it's with mine Ubuntu OS.Bioperl is successfully installed.